Appending to a list by adding to the previous value in Python
I have some repeat scenarios where I have an initial list, then I want to add some additional values to the end of the list by taking the last value and adding a constant to it.
I want to repeat this for some x amount of times, taking the previous list value and adding the same constant to it.
I'm quite new to Python and I have got a working approach per below.  I feel like I need the interator 'index' so that I can call the previous item in the list. It means the "items" variable is literally doing nothing which has me thinking that there would be a better way to do this. Any suggestions?
starting_list = [1, 5, 3]
increment = 7

additional_items = 5

for index, items in enumerate(range(additional_items), start=3):
    starting_list.append(starting_list[index - 1] + increment)

print(starting_list)

this gives me the desired output per below:
[1, 5, 3, 10, 17, 24, 31, 38]



by taking the last value and adding a constant to it

You can get the last value of the list using starting_list[-1]. This removes the need for the index variable altogether, simplifying the code like this:
starting_list = [1, 5, 3]
increment = 7

additional_items = 5

for _ in range(additional_items):
    starting_list.append(starting_list[-1] + increment)

print(starting_list)


Thanks Miran, I knew there must be a shorter way to do it. Works perfectly for what I needed.

starting_list = [1, 5, 3]
increment = 7

additional_items = 5

for index in range(3, 3+additional_items):
    starting_list.append(starting_list[index - 1] + increment)

print(starting_list)

Just remove the enumerate, and just iterate over indexes.
Additionally, instead of writting 3, if your goal is to always start at the end of the previous list, you can use it as a constant.
Therefor, you may change your code like that :
starting_list = [1, 5, 3]
increment = 7

additional_items = 5 # number of additional_items you want 
initial_list_size = len(starting_list)
final_list_size = initial_list_size + additional_items

for index in range(initial_list_size, final_list_size):
    starting_list.append(starting_list[index - 1] + increment)

print(starting_list)


Just for the sake of it, you could do this (though it's actually less readable than the accepted answer):
starting_list.extend(range(starting_list[-1] + increment, starting_list[-1] + increment * (additional_items + 1), increment))
